# Which Google Analytics Api client library-node or javascript to use for my website?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am making a website which displays report generated using google analytics data.My frontend is in React JS and backend in Node js and I have used the create-react-app boilerplate for React.I am really confused as to which client library -Node or Javascript to use for my website.Please could someone help me out..I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has 2 API's for getting reporting data: the core api v3 and the reporting api v4. For new projects I would suggest using the latest reporting api v4.

To use any of these api's I would use Google's officially supported Node.js client library: [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

I also wrote a [complete guide](https://glamdevhero.com/2018/07/08/the-definitive-node-js-guide-for-working-with-the-google-analytics-reporting-api-v4/) on how to work with Node.js and the Google Analytics Reporting API. This will definitely help you get started.